# How can I redirect individual emails on Exchange without forwarding them?

Tags: email, exchange, outlook-web-access

We have email to salesforce setup but sometimes we get emails arriving to different channels. If we forward them everything gets screwed up as we have the wrong message header.

So what we have tried is to set up a shared mailbox for emails to be moved to and then set up a transport rule to redirectmessageto the email to salesforce address.

This doesn't work as all the triggers in OWA exchange settings depend on the recipient or the sender rather than the message being located in a particular folder.

So love some ideas for a quick fix for this. Can it be done in powershell We should only have the problem for 4 weeks until the new message routing system makes it go away :) [i hope]

Comment: Do you accept the server-side solution only? Or it is acceptable to use redirect on client (Outlook)?

Comment: Redirect on client is ok.

Comment: One more question: by "wrong message header" you mean that you have different "From" or what?

Comment: Yes.The SF code works on the from. If that doesn't match that of the original sender then I have a problem. We also use the original time stamp.